# Method to list of attributes of a model which establishes a DB connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In old Rails versions one could call a Model by name in the console and get a list of all attributes. In the new versions that is not possible - at least not right away until a connection is established:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
>> Product
=> Product (call 'Product.connection' to establish a connection)
>>
```

I know that this is a feature and not a bug. And I know that a simple `Product.count` would establish the connection. I'm wondering what other method I could call to receive the list of attributes that automatically establishes the connection to the database. I'm looking for this output:

```
=> Product(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Comment: I haven't done it in console, but you can go to your DB folder and in the schema file this is all listed.

Comment: I would just do Product.new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [column_names](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/column_names) wich returns an Array of Model columns as string like :

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
>> Product.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"]
>>
```

or [columns_hash](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache/columns_hash) which returns more informations

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/application.rb` you can establish the connection like so:

```
console do
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```